# Type issue in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I've been struggling with this for over half an hour. I know it's something simple, but I am awful at types in Haskell, and even after reading the accepted answers to problems very similar to mine, I still cannot solve my problem - let alone understand it!

The code:

```
p108 = [filter (\[a,b] -> a>0 && b>0) (diophantinepairs n) | n <- [1..]]

diophantinepairs :: Integer -> [[Integer]]
diophantinepairs n = nub$map sort b
    where
        a = divisors n
        b = [[(n-d), n - (n^2)/d] | d <- a]
```

The error :

> ```
> 249:39:
>     No instance for (Fractional Integer)
>       arising from a use of `/'
>     Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
>     In the second argument of `(-)', namely `(n ^ 2) / d'
>     In the expression: n - (n ^ 2) / d
>     In the expression: [(n - d), n - (n ^ 2) / d]
> ```

Thanks, 
Sam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you read these kind of errors:

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer)
```

Translation: your program has an `Integer`, but you are using one of the methods of the `Fractional` class on it.

```
arising from a use of `/'
```

Translation: The method involved is `/`, which is part of the `Fractional` class.  `Integer` is not `Fractional`, so you cannot apply `/` to an integer.

Solution: Use `div` or `quot` instead.

I can get the same error in `ghci` easily enough:

```
Prelude> (1 :: Integer) / (2 :: Integer)

<interactive>:2:16:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer)
      arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the expression: (1 :: Integer) / (2 :: Integer)
    In an equation for `it': it = (1 :: Integer) / (2 :: Integer)
```

Alternate fix: use a `Fractional` type such as a `Rational` instead of `Integer`:

```
Prelude> (1 :: Integer) `div` (2 :: Integer)
0
Prelude> :m + Data.Ratio
Prelude Data.Ratio> (1 :: Rational) / (2 :: Rational)
1 % 2
```

Comment: Good answer covering alternatives.. In this particular case, assuming divisors works as advertised, d divides n so Sam can use div to get this Integer answer.

Comment: Note that `div` compute the quotient of an euclidean division, `quot` is a bit less mathematically interesting since it just mirror around 0, but on the other hand, `quot` is slightly faster on most hardware (being the CPU instruction) and given the fact that you're working (as many) with natural integers anyway...

Comment: @Jedai: And for `Integer`, they'll be the same speed, since `Integer` stores the sign and the magnitude separately.  At least for `Integer` larger than a word.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike in some languages, the `/` is not overloaded to work on Integers.  This makes sense: Integer "division" is not the same thing as rational divisions.  In Haskell

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

but as I said, `Integer` is not `Fractional` which is why you get

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer)
```

Instead you can use the `quot` or `div` functions which perform integer division.